# What kind of Makefile variable assignment is this?

Tags: variables, makefile, declaration

I've used simple makefiles for years, but only recently been assigned the task of learning the ins and outs of a large, complicated set of Autotools-generated makefiles which is used for a code base my employer has bought.  In these, I'm running into variable declarations like the following:

```
QOBJECT_MOCSRCS = $(QOBJECT_HEADER:%.h=.gen/moc_%.cpp) \
                  $(QOBJECT_SRCS:%.cpp=.gen/moc_%.cpp)

QOBJECT_DEPS = $(QOBJECT_MOCSRCS:%.cpp=.deps/%.Po)
```

My best guess from context is that these set up lists of names of files to be provided by the build process, eg., QOBJECT_MOCSRCS should end up as a list of (a) .h files, (b) .cpp files, based on the % stem names of a set of intermediate .cpp files which will be generated during the build, in a temporary directory ./gen.  This is used to store the moc_%.cpp files which are output as a result of a build of Qt files with Qt's moc tool...what is driving me crazy, is that I have been unable to find anything in any *make* documentation I've got (mostly the GNU make manual) that tells me what this style of declaration is called, so I can track it down and get a grip on the syntax. The contents of the $() look sort of like rules, and the nearest equivalents in the GNU make manual seem to be rules specifying target-specific variable values, but I have no idea whether this is anywhere near a correct reading.  Can anyone point me to an appropriate reference for study?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is called substitution references, http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html#Substitution-Refs

Comment: Dorothy: if you feel that your question has been answered please use the check icon next to the answer to mark it as such.  Thanks!