# Makefile: what syntax is this: $(@:foobar_%=%)?

Tags: makefile

I have the following Makefile snippet, which I don't quite understand. In particular, what is the meaning of `$(@:foobar_%=%)`? Thanks.

```
foobar_test:
        @echo $(@:foobar_%=%) # will print test
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What kind of Makefile variable assignment is this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469717/what-kind-of-makefile-variable-assignment-is-this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a [Substitution Reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs):

Another type of substitution reference lets you use the full power of the patsubst function. It has the same form ‘$(var:a=b)’ described above, except that now a must contain a single ‘%’ character. This case is equivalent to ‘$(patsubst a,b,$(var))’. See Functions for String Substitution and Analysis, for a description of the patsubst function.

```
For example:

     foo := a.o b.o c.o
     bar := $(foo:%.o=%.c)

sets ‘bar’ to ‘a.c b.c c.c’.
```